# « Liste de stationnement » ou « liste parking » ?

Tags: traduction, allemand

Pour traduire le mot allemand *Parkplatzliste* en Français, lequel est mieux entre *liste de stationnement* et *liste parking* ?

Comment: Could you include some detail? For example, what is a "Parkplatzliste", where do you see the word?

Comment: @Alenanno: It's the title of a report I need to translate. Parkplatzliste is as said German, and I thought it should be obvious for an English speaker that this means "Parking list" in English, especially with parking mentioned in one of the French possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, *parking* was used in France, whereas *stationnement* was used more often in Quebec, in Ontario I've seen both.

Answer (score -3):

*Parking* n'est pas un mot français, il est utilisé par certains francophones en tant qu'anglicisme pour désigner un stationnement, à même titre que *week-end* pour "fin de semaine".

Je dirais donc personnellement que *liste de stationnement* est mieux

Comment: *Parking* est un mot français, puisqu'il s'emploie couramment en français, est présent dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parking) et même dans le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/parking). Je pense aussi que la plupart des francophones (au moins en France) comprennent mieux et emploient davantage *parking* que *stationnement*. C'est encore plus vrai pour *week-end* et *fin de semaine* (à part peut-être au Québec).

Comment: C'est vrai que parking est bien maintenant un mot français, mais je crois que cette réponse démontre bien comment il ne faut pas utiliser "parking" au Québec, parce qu'on le considère effectivement comme une forme d'anglicisme! Qui est le public-cible de la traduction?